# how to change the color of selected row in tdbgrid in delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tdbgrid

Iam creating an application in delphi where I want to change the color of  selected row of tdbgrid which is based on search ..can it be possible ..

Comment: How about you search before asking a question? I am pretty sure this has been covered multiple times. On StackOverflow and elsewhere... Yep, just typeing "site:stackoverflow.com dbgrid color row" in Google brings up about 87 results on the subject...

Comment: Or `[delphi] dbgrid color row` in the SO search field

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change DBGRID row color on field value in delphi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800103/change-dbgrid-row-color-on-field-value-in-delphi)

Answer (score 5):

I always find About.com a good resource.

See here for an example which may help you.
http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/l/aa031699.htm