# How to change TDBGrld row colour when a field value is changed

Tags: delphi, colors, tdbgrid

*(Minimal RepEx at the end)*

I have a DBGrid (actually a TSMDBgrid) populated by a query.
One field, `payment_made`, is Boolean and displays in the grid as a checkbox either ticked or unticked.  depending upon the field value. This is the only field that can be edited. Initially all rows are unticked

I'm using the often published DrawColumnCell() code below to change the whole row colour to blue if the Boolean field on that row gets changed to checked (true) and back to white if it subsequently gets unchecked (false).
I want all rows that are checked to remain blue.

The code I use is

```
procedure TFrmBulkSubdPaymentRecord.SMDBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
                                                            const Rect: TRect; 
                                                            DataCol: Integer; 
                                                            Column: TColumn; 
                                                             State: TGridDrawState);
//see   https://www.thoughtco.com/change-coloring-in-tdbgrid-component-4077252    
begin
if MyQuery1.FieldByName('payment_made').AsBoolean = true  then
     SMDBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color :=  $00ffff99//pale blue
 else
     SMDBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color :=  clwhite;
SMDBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell (Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

When starting with a white grid, if I check the `payment_made` box in ,say, row 3 the whole row goes blue.

If I check another row, say row 6 then that whole row row goes blue.

If I then uncheck row 3 the whole of that row goes white again

But, if I then check row 3 again, this time just the `payment_made` cell goes blue, not the whole row

It looks like could be something to do with the `OnDrawColumnCell()` not being called for every cell.

Am I doing this the right way or have I missed something?

I've looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16800103/change-dbgrid-row-color-on-field-value-in-delphi) and several other related posts but it appears I am doing it right (although obviously not)

No other processing is done when the field is clicked as it's all done afterwards in a loop that deals with each checked row in turn.

*Incidentally, I use*

```
 if MyQuery1.FieldByName('payment_made').AsBoolean = true then
```

*simply to make the code more readable. I realise that the `= true` is unnecessary and I can live with the extra few microseconds this might add.*

**Minimal Reproducible example** (written in Delphi 2009 and using TSMDBgrid from SM components (although problem seem to exist with the TDGGrid as well)

**The .dfm**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 553
  ClientWidth = 640
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 344
    Top = 56
    Width = 61
    Height = 13
    Caption = '<--- TDBGrid'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 344
    Top = 165
    Width = 75
    Height = 13
    Caption = '<--- TSMDBGrid'
  end
  object DBGrid1: TDBGrid
    Left = 8
    Top = 16
    Width = 321
    Height = 97
    TabOrder = 0
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -11
    TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    TitleFont.Style = []
  end
  object SMDBGrid1: TSMDBGrid
    Left = 8
    Top = 137
    Width = 321
    Height = 104
    Options = [dgEditing, dgTitles, dgIndicator, dgColumnResize, dgColLines, dgRowLines, dgTabs, dgConfirmDelete, dgCancelOnExit]
    TabOrder = 1
    TitleFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    TitleFont.Color = clWindowText
    TitleFont.Height = -11
    TitleFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    TitleFont.Style = []
    Flat = False
    BandsFont.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    BandsFont.Color = clWindowText
    BandsFont.Height = -11
    BandsFont.Name = 'Tahoma'
    BandsFont.Style = []
    Groupings = <>
    GridStyle.Style = gsCustom
    GridStyle.OddColor = clWindow
    GridStyle.EvenColor = clWindow
    TitleHeight.PixelCount = 24
    FooterColor = clBtnFace
    ExOptions = [eoBooleanAsCheckBox, eoENTERlikeTAB, eoKeepSelection, eoStandardPopup, eoBLOBEditor, eoTitleWordWrap, eoFilterAutoApply]
    RegistryKey = 'Software\Scalabium'
    RegistrySection = 'SMDBGrid'
    WidthOfIndicator = 11
    DefaultRowHeight = 24
    ScrollBars = ssHorizontal
  end
  object btnSetTrue: TButton
    Left = 480
    Top = 111
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'btnSetTrue'
    TabOrder = 2
    OnClick = btnSetTrueClick
  end
  object btnSetFalse: TButton
    Left = 480
    Top = 160
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'btnSetFalse'
    TabOrder = 3
    OnClick = btnSetFalseClick
  end
  object Memo1: TMemo
    Left = 8
    Top = 304
    Width = 609
    Height = 241
    Lines.Strings = (
      'Top grid is TDBGrid, botton grid is TSMDBGrid'
      'Both use DataSource1 as their datasource'
      'Both have the same code for their OnDBGrid1DrawColumnCell'
      
        'When the field '#39'payment_made'#39' is TRUE the whole row should be bl' +
        'ue, when it is false the whole rowq should be white'
      ''
      'Correct operation'
      '=========='
      ''
      'Change the value of the boolean field using the buttons. '
      
        'This operates correctly, the whole row in each grid changes to b' +
        'lue or whire  correctly. '
      'problem evident.'
      ''
      'To reproduce the problem'
      '==============='
      ''
      
        'Change the boolean field from true to false or vice versa using ' +
        'either the check box in SMDBGrid or by typing true '
      'or false in the DBGrid.'
      
        'Sometimes only one cell on the row changes to the correct colour' +
        ', leaving other cells on the row the wrong colour.')
    TabOrder = 4
  end
  object ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet
    Aggregates = <>
    Params = <>
    Left = 376
    Top = 240
  end
  object DataSource1: TDataSource
    Left = 448
    Top = 240
  end
end
```

**The .pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, SMDBGrid, Grids, DBGrids, DB, DBClient;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    SMDBGrid1: TSMDBGrid;
    btnSetTrue: TButton;
    btnSetFalse: TButton;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
      DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
    procedure SMDBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
      DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
    procedure btnSetTrueClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnSetFalseClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnSetFalseClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('payment_made').AsBoolean := false;
 SMDBGrid1.Refresh  ;
 DBGrid1.refresh
end;

procedure TForm1.btnSetTrueClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('payment_made').AsBoolean := true;
 SMDBGrid1.Refresh  ;
 DBGrid1.refresh
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
 if ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('payment_made').AsBoolean = true  then
     DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color :=  $00ffff99//pale blue
 else
     DBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color :=  clwhite;
DBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell (Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
    //define dataset fields
    ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('payment_made', ftBoolean);
    ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('second_column', ftString, 10);
    ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
    ClientDataSet1.LogChanges := False;

    //put in one row of data
    ClientDataSet1.Append; // insertfirst row
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('payment_made').AsBoolean := false;
    ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('second_column').AsString := 'row one';
    ClientDataSet1.Post;

    //leave it in editing mode (although this doesn't seem to make any difference)
    ClientDataSet1.Edit;

    //set option for SMDBgrid to display booleans as a checkbox
    SMDBGrid1.ExOptions :=   SMDBGrid1.ExOptions + [eoBooleanAsCheckBox] ;

    //link components together
    DataSource1.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;
    SMDBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;
    DBGrid1.DataSource := DataSource1;

    //point the grids to their respective  OnDrawColumnCell routines
    DBGrid1.OnDrawColumnCell := DBGrid1DrawColumnCell ;
    SMDBGrid1.OnDrawColumnCell := SMDBGrid1DrawColumnCell ;

end;

procedure TForm1.SMDBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if ClientDataSet1.FieldByName('payment_made').AsBoolean = true  then
     SMDBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color :=  $00ffff99//pale blue
 else
     SMDBGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color :=  clwhite;
SMDBGrid1.DefaultDrawColumnCell (Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;


end.
```

Comment: I tested the code you list and it works perfectly here. I used a standard DBGrid. Maybe this is a bug in TSMDBGrid. I suggest you do a quick test with a standard DBGrid to see if it works for you.

Comment: how did you get the checkbox in an ordinary tdbgrid? I used the smtdbgrid solely because it has a property to easily display boolean data  as checkboxes without writing lots of code to do it

Comment: I have no checkbox, I test the value of a field to change the row color. I verified the color stay correct when I edit the field. I suspect TSMDBGrid do not correctly invalidate the row when the checkbox updated the table and only the cell containing the checkbox is invalidate and so only that one is redrawn. That's why I said it is a bug in TSMDBGrid (Or maybe you use it incorrectly). I asked you to verify with a standard DBGrid that nothing else is wrong. If it doesn't work with standard DBGrid, then you have a bug in code you don't show it.

Comment: If you provide a complete standalone minimal reproducible example (See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I will check it. Having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask may also help you.

Comment: OK, done that. Instructions are in the memo

Comment: Anyone tried my MRE?. Its certainly reproducible at my end

Comment: Your MRE requires a non standard component that most people have not installed. So now you have to wait until someone having that component see your question or someone want to take the time to install the component. Did you try to contact the author?

Comment: I get the same symptoms with the TDBGRID which is standard and included in the MRE  The TSMTDBgrid could simply be removed from the  MRE . But my post did say I was using SMDBgrid (which is reasonably common) and in response you asked for a MRE. I assumed that meant you were able to compile it. Is there anything in the code that would cause the TDBgrid to behave in the same way?